# no field or association named when use 2layer query

Tags: mysql, symfony

I try this in mysql by terminal

```
select doc.id from Document doc where doc.id not in (select ck.document_id from CheckDoc ck where ck.requestItem_id = 7);
```

and it work sucssecfuly.

but when i use it in symfony, it's not work. i get this error:

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 148 near 'doc_id': 
Error: Class FWZ\RequestBundle\Entity\CheckDoc has no field or association named doc_id
```

my tables:

Document table:
id , title and  OnetoMany relation by CheckDoc table

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CheckDoc", mappedBy="document" )
 */
protected $checkdoc;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->checkdoc = new ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * Add checkdoc
 *
 * @param FWZ\RequestBundle\Entity\CheckDoc $checkdoc
 */
public function addCheckdoc(\FWZ\RequestBundle\Entity\CheckDoc $checkdoc)
{
    $this->checkdoc[] = $checkdoc;
}

/**
 * Get checkdoc
 *
 * @return Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
 */
public function getCheckdoc()
{
    return $this->checkdoc;
}
```

---

RequestItem table: 
id , title and OneToMany relation by CheckDoc table

```
/**
   * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CheckDoc", mappedBy="request"  )
  */
protected $checkdoc;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->checkdoc = new ArrayCollection();
}



/**
 * Add checkdoc
 *
 * @param FWZ\RequestBundle\Entity\CheckDoc $checkdoc
 */
public function addCheckdoc(\FWZ\RequestBundle\Entity\CheckDoc $checkdoc)
{
    $this->checkdoc[] = $checkdoc;
}

/**
 * Get checkdoc
 *
 * @return Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
 */
public function getCheckdoc()
{
    return $this->checkdoc;
}
```

---

CheckDoc table
id, title , ManyToOne relations with Document and RequestItem tables

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="RequestItem", inversedBy="checkdoc" )
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="requestItem_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */

protected $request;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Document", inversedBy="checkdoc" )
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="doc_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */

protected $document;



/**
 * Set request
 *
 * @param FWZ\RequestBundle\Entity\RequestItem $request
 */
public function setRequest(\FWZ\RequestBundle\Entity\RequestItem $request)
{
    $this->request = $request;
}

/**
 * Get request
 *
 * @return FWZ\RequestBundle\Entity\RequestItem 
 */
public function getRequest()
{
    return $this->request;
}

/**
 * Set document
 *
 * @param FWZ\RequestBundle\Entity\Document $document
 */
public function setDocument(\FWZ\RequestBundle\Entity\Document $document)
{
    $this->document = $document;
}

/**
 * Get document
 *
 * @return FWZ\RequestBundle\Entity\Document 
 */
public function getDocument()
{
    return $this->document;
}
```

---

and my query in controller

```
$query = $em->createQuery(
                'SELECT doc.id 
                FROM FWZRequestBundle:Document doc 
                WHERE doc.id  not in (
                                select ck.doc_id 
                                from FWZRequestBundle:CheckDoc ck
                                where ck.requestItem_id = 7 )'
                );           

 $documents = $query->getResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your query to:

```
 $query = $em->createQuery(
                    'SELECT doc.id 
                    FROM FWZRequestBundle:Document doc 
                    WHERE doc.id  not in (
                                    select ck.document.doc_id 
                                    from FWZRequestBundle:CheckDoc ck
                                    where ck.request.requestItem_id = 7 )'
                    );           

     $documents = $query->getResult();
```

It's just a typo: you used `doc_id` instead of `document_id` as in the well running query you've showed us.

Comment: when change it to your code, i get this error:

[Semantical Error] line 0, col 148 near 'document_id
': Error: Class FWZ\RequestBundle\Entity\CheckDoc has no field or association named document_id

Comment: then the first query should not work, also. Maybe you forgot to mention us something. Try ck.id instead of ck.document_id

Comment: i dont need to ck.id, i need ck.document_id from chechdoc table.
but, when i try ck.id, i get error about requestItem_id

Comment: I'm not familiar with jquery, but you can try tu use ck.document.doc_id and ck.request.requestItem_id instead of your current values.

Comment: i try it too, but get this error: [Syntax Error] line 0, col 156: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_FROM, got '.'